# Is there a workaround for an elevatr error in R?

Tags: r, r-sp, elevatr

I am trying to extract elevation values for a series of coordinates using the `elevatr` package in R. According to one of the vignettes (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/elevatr/vignettes/introduction_to_elevatr.html), the following code should work:

```
require(sp)
require(elevatr)

ex.x <- c(-9.979167, -9.937500, -9.895833)
ex.y <- c(64.97917, 64.97917, 64.97917)
ex.df <- data.frame(x = ex.x, y = ex.y)
ex.sp <- sp::SpatialPoints(ex.df, proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

ex.epqs <- get_elev_point(EU.elev.sp, src = "epqs")
```

This code works up until I try to extract the elevation values, at which point it returns the following error:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'CRSobj' in selecting a method for function 'spTransform': NA
```

Does anybody know the reason this error occurs or how to fix it? Is `elevatr` broken or is there something else going on?

Comment: What version of sp are you currently running?  There has been a lot of changes under the hood on how PROJ and friends deal with CRSs.  I've tried to deal with the changes as best as I can but I am sure I haven't accounted for all possibilities.

I am running sp 1.4-6 and elevatr 0.4.2 and the code above does not error (although epqs is only for US locations and I assume the code should have ex.sp as input for get_elev_point,and not EU.elev.sp).

Comment: in my case a reinstallation of rdgal with install.packages("rgdal", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org") and setting rgdal::set_proj_search_paths("C:/Users/Christof/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/rgdal/proj") as described here github.com/jhollist/elevatr/issues/48#issuecomment-1059802332 had fixed the same problem